# Angular2 Directive: How to detect DOM changes

Tags: javascript, dom, typescript, angular, skrollr

I want to implement Skrollr as an Angular2 attribute directive.

So, the format may be:

```
<body my-skrollr>
</body>
```

However, in order to implement this, I need to be able to detect changes in the DOM in child elements below the containing tag (in this case, <body>), so that I can call skrollr.init().refresh(); and update the library to work with the new content.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this that I'm not aware of, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Angular does not provide something built-in for that purpose. You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect DOM changes.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-skrollr]',
  ...
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
      });   
    });
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

    this.observer.observe(this.elRef.nativeElement, config);
  }
}
```

Comment: In MutationObserver constructor it should be "mutations" instead of "mutation"

Comment: thank you for this... Can someone tell me wha th opposite of what this would be... i.e. detecting nothing changed?  if that makes sense.  lol I need something to turn off the variable.

Comment: Perhaps you can check that no mutation event was emitted for a specific amount of time?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew - Surely you would simply set a state to "false" and then just change to true when something changes?

Comment: Don't forget to call `this.observer.disconnect();` inside the `ngOnDestroy()` method

Comment: Is it safe to use ElementRef.nativeElement?  I thought that posed XSS risk for the application.

Comment: Using nativeElement is not related to XSS as long as you do not use it to append user-generated content (directly or indirectly) to the DOM. Access to `nativeElement` was frowned upon at the beginning of Angular 2 development because it would be incompatible with server-side rendering and web-worker but they are not used widely anyway and only the few that do need to take care. The current status is as far as I remember, that passing around `nativeElement` is now compatible with SSR/WW, but accessing methods or properties is not.