# Angular2, ZoneJS and externally changed DOM

Tags: angularjs, dom, angular, zonejs

I need some help concerning an externally changed DOM within an Angular2 RC1 web app. The scenario is simple: I do have a component with an according template that contains an empty div with an ID like this

```
<div id="my-svg-canvas"></div>
```

The typescripted component has an ngOnInit method that triggers a function from a plain JS file that is included via script-tag in the index.html. That function renders an SVG into the above listed "div" tag. The SVG contains some a-elements with on-click directives that reference several methods in my component.

That worked fine back then in Angular1 after calling $scope.$apply() after the SVG was completely written. Now, in Angular2 the respective methods in my component are not triggered.

I know, that ZoneJS is now responsible for detecting changes in the DOM. I was hoping that this is done automatically for the whole DOM rendered inside an Angular-managed component. Next try was to inject NgZone in my component and explicitly run the rendering function therein, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {renderSVG(this.myData, "my-svg-canvas");})
}
```

No success either :-/ Moreover, I registered a MutationObserver (see this thread: [Angular2 Directive: How to detect DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130393/angular2-directive-how-to-detect-dom-changes)), since the problem occurred a little similar to me. It hasn't fired either, though.

I have no clue where to look for, no error message to cling to :-???

Note: It was necessary to use "on-click" instead of "(click)" since the SVG rendering framework refused to set invalid attributes. Obviously attributes starting with a bracket are fine for HTML, but not for XML. However, this should not be the problem, since both directives are perfectly exchangable.

PS:

The rendering method called makes use of the SVG.js framework and looks like this:

```
function renderSVG(dataParam, elementIdParam) {
  draw = SVG(elementIdParam).spof();
  initAndPaint(draw, dataParam);
  return draw; 
 }
```

And the  tag generated by the SVG.js lib

```
<a id="SvgjsA1033" on-click="showVal('W1')" class="union">
```

When I paste the generated SVG code into my template, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Angular is going to parse your dynamically added HTML (see [Angular2 - catch/subscribe to (click) event in dynamically added HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116770/angular2-catch-subscribe-to-click-event-in-dynamically-added-html)).

So, after you call `renderSVG()`, you'll probably need to traverse the DOM and find the newly added `a` elements and then manually add (and later remove) an event handler for each one.

See [Dynamically add event listener in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2).

For a more involved approach, see [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2).

Comment: The solution provided in the first links is really giving me the creeps :-) 

I gave the DynamicLoaderComponent a chance and it actually works, although it feels like a time warp back in the middle ages compared to the one-liner in Angular1. Fair enough, we're dealing with the RC, a better solution should be presented though.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I've added the implementation to your post and flagged it as "accepted"

Comment: @user3802631, I completely agree.  We need something simpler than the DynamicLoaderComponent.  It looks like your edit was rejected.  I suggest you add it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would move your code into the `ngAfterViewInit` hook method of your component:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {renderSVG(this.myData, "my-svg-canvas");})
}
```

Moreover you should reference your DOM element using the `ViewChild` decorator:

```
<div #mySvgCanvas"></div>
```

and

```
@ViewChild('mySvgCanvas')
mySvgCanvasElt: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var elt = this.mySvgCanvasElt.nativeElement;
```

I don't think that using zones explicitly is required here...

Comment: Thanks Thierry for the quick response. I did as you said, still not working. I've checked the viewchild property after the rendering happened and the whole SVG is there, which is good. Furthermore, I've added another viewchild next to the canvas:  an <a> tag with an on-click directive just as in the SVG to see if or how their ElementRef.nativeElemtens differ. The single <a>-nativeelement has a __zone_symbol__eventtasks array attached, all the <a> tags in the SVG haven't. 

I've run the SVG rendering within ngZone and once without. No difference :-/

Comment: Could you provide some extract of yoour `renderSvg` method? Just to see what it looks like...

Comment: Of course. Please see the PS section I've added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Thanks! Did you try to use the `ChangeDetectorRef` class and its `detectChanges` method?

Comment: Yep, I've tried detectChanges and markForCheck() with all combinations of ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr so I can have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Here it is with the ChangeDetectorRef: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/hf180P6nkxXtJDusPdLb

Comment: Hey Thierry, just to let you know: I've created a [spin off thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497360/how-let-angular2-rc1-know-about-changed-dom) from this one with a much simpler example and the plunkr added in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Rajcok's link (see "For a more involved approach") to a solution using `DynamicLoaderComponent` in the accepted answer works. As a closure for this thread this is my implementation:

```
constructor(private loader: DynamicComponentLoader, private injector:Injector) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  let tournamentCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  renderKOTournamentSVG(this.tournament, tournamentCanvas);

  @Component({
    selector: 'canvas-component',
    template: tournamentCanvas.outerHTML)}
  class CanvasComponent {}

  this.loader.loadAsRoot(CanvasComponent, "canvas-component", this.injector);
 }
```